# Is it just me or is the ~/Sites folder gone in Lion?

Tags: osx-lion

It appears that the `~/Sites` directory no longer exists in OS X Lion. I preferred working on sites there than in `/Library/WebServer/Documents`. Is there any way to change it back, or set it up so that I can work on sites in `~/Sites` and have the files automatically moved to `/Library/WebServer/Documents`?

Comment: I still have `~/Sites`. I upgraded, did you do a clean install?

Comment: I don't have Sites in a clean install.

Comment: Can you just create ~/Sites and put files there?

Comment: I did a clean install. But creating a "Sites" folder fully restores the missing functionality. You can go to http://imac.local/~user/ as you used to be able to do and you get a custom icon. I guess they just figure most people don't need it and those that do can create it.

Answer (score 17):

If you enable Web Sharing in System Preferences, you now have the option to create a **Personal Website Folder** which essentially creates a `~/Sites` directory.

Comment: I do not see the option to enable Web Sharing

Comment: Internet Sharing

Answer (score 3):

You can link them together with a *Symlink*:

> `cd ~`
>    `ln -s /Library/WebServer/Documents Sites`

This will make `~/Sites` behave as a alias of `/Library/WebServer/Documents` on the filesystem level, so it should work for all applications that you use.

The ideal way to fix this would be to fix the configuration for the webserver to support `~/Sites` for each user again, but if you're the only user using the system, this method described here should work.

Comment: Thanks. See my comment above. I just created a "Sites" folder and full functionality was restored.

Comment: @Oliver That's great! If you post it as an answer, you can accept it (which is allowed (and encouraged!) here if it is indeed the solution).

Answer (score 2):

Just turning on "Web Sharing" doesn't add the Sites folder. You have to also click the "Create Personal Website Folder" to the right.